# How to disable AWS Lambda Edge Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using Cloud front + Lambda Edge. Each Lambda invocation creates a cloud watch log entry in the closest AWS region. This results in lots of Cloud watch log streams scattered around the globe in all possible regions.

As the default retention of Cloud watch logs is to never expire, both the data and the number of streams builds quickly.

Locating these logs and setting a reasonable retention is a chore.

Is there a way to disable these logs completely in Lambda Edge?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166504/disable-cloudwatch-to-monitor-logs-for-lambda-function

Comment: Looks like it is exactly the same question and answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the CloudWatch permissions from your Lambda execution role, it will stop putting logs there. By default, every Lambda function gets this permission.